# use of function connect() in the constructor

Tags: c++, events, opengl, wxwidgets

I don't understand the use of the function connect() in the constructor of the some classes. I thought that it was for "connecting" the events with the graphical part of my program, but it makes me the same if I don't use any connect function in the constructor. Here is one part of my code for example:

```
#include "VueOpenGL.h"
#include "wx/wx.h"
#include "wx/glcanvas.h"
#include "wx/progdlg.h"
using namespace std;

//Constructor of the class "VueOpenGL"

VueOpenGL::VueOpenGL(wxWindow* parent, wxSize const& taille, wxPoint const& position)
:wxGLCanvas(parent, wxID_ANY, position, taille,
 wxSUNKEN_BORDER|wxFULL_REPAINT_ON_RESIZE|WX_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER)
{
  //Events
Connect(wxEVT_KEY_DOWN, wxKeyEventHandler(VueOpenGL::OnKeyDown));
} 

...

void VueOpenGL::OnKeyDown(wxKeyEvent& event) {
    switch(event.GetKeyCode()) {
        case WXK_LEFT:
             instructions_1;
        break;
        case WXK_RIGHT:
             instructions_2;
        break;
     }
}
```

(All the prototypes are in the VueOpenGL.h)

Comment: Well, did you try what heppens when you press a key? Events are not about getting things on the screen, but to deliver (user) input to the parts of your program dealing with it.

Comment: @datenwolf Yes, I meant, when I press a key everything happens like it wasn't any "Connect" in the constructor..So my question is: when do I need to use connect?

Answer (score 1):

You are not showing us everything. Without `Connect(wxEVT_KEY_DOWN)` the key press events wouldn't be delivered to your handler. So if it's still being called, it must be connected in some other way or maybe you're just not testing the code you think you are testing (e.g. rebuilding after commenting out the line containing Connect() failed and you are still running the old version).